# nVidia driver update causes unbootable system

Tags: boot, nvidia

I used Ubuntu Driver Update manager to install the recommended driver. I can't get into the GUI anymore, system hangs at terminal.

I have read that there are terminal commands to purge the old drivers, but how do I get into a useful terminal, at this point?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you got the terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you got the terminal run the below command to remove `xorg.conf` file

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

After installing nvidia drivers,it generates `xorg.conf` file.This file causes the system not to boot.
If you does'nt got the terminal press `Ctrl+Alt+(F2-F10)` when booting.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask if there is a better way to install nVidia drivers?

Comment: Installing nvidia drivers may cause several problems,it is better to install nvidia drivers with `bumblebeed`.

Comment: Mmmmkay. Will do.